# VLC video streaming on raspberry pi generates stream_out_standard error

Tags: pi-4, streaming-video, vlc

I am trying to stream video using raspberry pi 4. I attached a raspberry pi camera to the board and enabled the camera in the config.
I have also installed vlc to the rspi and created a `rtsp-stream.sh` script which contains the following code:

```
raspivid -o - -t 0 -rot 180 -w 1920 -h 1080 -fps 30 -b 2000000 | cvlc -vvv stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/stream}' :demux=h264
```

Using both methods `ping raspberry.local` and `ifconfig` to get the address of the rspi, I then opened a new network on VLC media player on Mac and passed URL as `rtsp://rspi_ip:8554/stream`.

However, I received the following error in VLC log.

> stream_out_standard error: no suitable sout access module for 'file{no-overwrite}/raw://(null)'
> main error: stream chain failed for `standard{mux=raw,access=file{no-overwrite},dst=""}'
> main error: cannot start stream output instance, aborting

Any idea on how to solve this issue?

Comment: You could also post your question here https://forum.videolan.org/index.php?

Comment: try to get viewing and streaming working separately.